# SetPlaceholderText NetOffice

Tags: c#, netoffice

Hello i'm tring to use netoffce to write word addin and face a strange problem i can't set text to new content control in word i know this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0c03837b-aca1-4cb6-81b7-f4fac8f36a04/possible-bug-in-wordcontentcontrol topic also https://netoffice.codeplex.com/discussions/471162 but can't figure out how to pass correct arguments to SetPlaceholderText method.

Any Help ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use a specific overload in NetOffice, you need to set the arguments that you don't want to use to Type.Missing.